# Writing the header file of my own library

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, static-libraries, header-files

I write some functions to use dinamic arrays in c, without the problem of pointers ecc. , and
now that i write enough code to use it properly, i want to encapsulate all this functions in a library.

Anyway in many of this function i use `memcpy()` method of the `string.h`.

So my question is:

- Need i to include `string.h` in the `.h` file?
- if i use `string.h` in the application where i will include my own library, will it be compilated two times?
- is there a way to optimising the compilation?

There aren't some guides about it online, and if there are, they are so ambiguos and confusing.

I found something about the `ifdef` but i don't really understand how and why use it.

Can somebody give me an example of the header file with a similar scenario, or at least a tutorial for writing header files?

This is the first time that i try to write a library in c, so all tips will be appreciate.

Comment: You need to include `<string.h>` is the file where you use `memcpy`. If you don't do it in your header file, then you don't need to include `<string.h>` in your header file.

Comment: You need to learn about linking, before continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header file will be shared between the final application and your library. Therefore, the best place to include `<string.h>` is your header file.

Do not worry about system or standard headers being included more than once. They normally have protective `#ifdef`s which take care of including the code only once.

As a good practice you can also insert a custom `#ifdef` in your header. For instance, your header file would look like this:

```
/* Beginning of header file */
#ifndef ALEX_XXX_HEADER

#define ALEX_XXX_HEADER

/* Your header constants, prototypes, etc. here */

#endif
/* End of header file */
```

In this way, the compiler will first check whether `_ALEX_XXX_HEADER` has been defined. If it hasn't, it means it is the first time it hits this file. Then, it defines your header macro `_ALEX_XXX_HEADER` and processes all the code in the header.

If the header is included more than once, the next time the compiler finds the `##ifndef ALEX_XXX_HEADER` line, it will skip the entire `#ifndef` clause because `ALEX_XXX_HEADER` was already defined the first time. In other words, it will skip the entire header file. As a result, the header code will be included once only.

Comment: Header files should only define constants and function calls, so they should NOT include other headers. That would add all of the string functions to the namespace of every file that includes this header.

Comment: Note that all names beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter are [*reserved*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers).

Comment: _Your header file will be shared between the final application and your library. Therefore, the best place to include <string.h> is your header file._ no, we don't do that. Already nothing says that the source file which uses the library will use functions of string.h

Comment: Since it's a shared file, I too include other headers like <string.h> in my custom header file. It saves me code space.

Comment: Thanks, i can continue now. For the future, i will focus about linker works.

Comment: Just another ask, is there a define of the string.h that I can use to trigger the macro?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @GodDoesBAU